# How do I unsubscribe from a Launchpad bug?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

My machine reported a bug to Launchpad, which was then marked as a duplicate of [another bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331-updates/+bug/1268257). I am now getting comments from everybody on that bug, and there are a lot of them. How do I unsubscribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short version:**

- Visit the original bug (the one your bug has been marked a duplicate of)
- Add `/+subscribe` to the end of the URL and follow the instructions

**Long version:**

Locate the unsubscribe link on the bug page:

- Visit the original bug (the one your bug has been marked a duplicate of)
- Scroll down and look on the right for a box that starts "You are [PENCIL ICON] subscribed..."

  - This is *under* the long "Duplicates of this bug" list and *above* the long "Other bug subscribers" list
  - You can add `#portlet-subscription` to the end of the bug URL to jump there automatically. For example, `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331-updates/+bug/1268257#portlet-subscription`

To simply unsubscribe:

- Click the "Mute bug mail" link

For other options:

- Click "Edit bug mail"
- Pick an option (I've highlighted two that might be helpful):

  - Mute all emails from this bug
  - Receive all emails about this bug
  - **Subscribe to all notifications except comments for this bug**
  - **Only receive an email when the bug is closed**
- Click on "Other subscriptions"

  - You may want to unsubscribe from these too

**Additional notes:**

Avoid posting any comments yourself, unless in response to a developer needing information in order to fix the bug. Even if others post inflammatory comments.

You may want to consider updating the description to direct others, as I have done in the linked bug. But I'm not actually sure about the policy on this.